# Plot pandas dataframe as histogram with different colors

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of the following form

```
df= pd.DataFrame([[1,100],[-1,50],[1,140],[1,300],[-1,400]],columns=['key','size'])
```

I would like to plot an histogram of the column `size` where in the x-axis the value of each bin is the index of each row, and the height of the histogram for a given bin is the value of `df['size']`. Also, I would like the bar in a given bin to be colored in red if `key==-1` or green if `key==1`.

I know how to make plots with vertical bars - I just call `df['size'].plot(kind='bar')`. How can I color each bar accordingly to the value of `key`?
I couldn't find a way to do so.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make custom plots with categorical variables, I recommend you to look the `seaborn` library.

> Seaborn is a Python data visualization library based on matplotlib. It
> provides a high-level interface for drawing attractive and informative
> statistical graphics.

[Link to the see more about Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org). It adds some extra tools that can be very helpful with these types of plots. In your case, the `seaborn.barplot` function handles it very easily. You just do

```
import seaborn as sns

>>> sns.barplot(x=list(df.index), y='size', hue='key', data=df,
                dodge=False, palette={-1: 'red', 1: 'green'})
```

Where `hue` are your categorical values, you can specify the color for each type with the `pallette` parameter.

It produces this graph:

[image]

Comment: you might need to add `dodge=False` to get the bar spacing correct

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve a bar plot with the [`df.plot.bar(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) method.

<strike>However, it is not really designed to choose colors the way you want, but you can change them afterwards as follows:</strike>

**Edit:** Actually you can choose right color directly, as suggested in another answer:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 100], [-1, 50], [1, 140], [1, 300], [-1, 400]],
    columns=["key", "size"],
)
colors_mapping = {1: "red", -1: "green"}

ax = df.plot.bar(
    y="size",
    color=df["key"].replace(colors_mapping),
    legend=False,
)

#for bar, key in zip(ax.patches, df["key"]):
#    bar.set_color(colors_mapping[key])


plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
df['size'].plot(
    kind='bar',
    color=df['key'].replace({1:'green', -1:'red'}),
)
```

Output:

[image]